# Is it possible to use the Scanner outside the main method and still call it in?

Tags: java, debugging, input, interface

So what im trying to do is to use my scanner method to go save the inputs that the users put in thats inside the for loop, but how do i call the certain type of input they place in? What i mean by this is, lets say the user places is in an input of 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 as the input for the question method and answer method. In the main method, or any method, how can i call in the input of 10, or 12.

```
package com.ez.ez;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReWrittingBetterCode{
        public static void Questions(){
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a question "+i+"/10");
        String firstQuestion = scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
    public static void Answer() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter a answer "+i+"/10");
        String answerAnswer = scanner.nextLine();
        }

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Questions();
        Answer();

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate an array to hold the questions.  Then when you prompt for the answers you can repeat the questions.  To be consistent with  your loops, you should have single variable called `noq` or something for number of questions, and use that everywhere when you are using for loops.

```
static int noq = 10;
static String[] questions = new String[noq];
static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Questions();
    Answer();

}

public static void Questions() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= noq; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter a question " + i + "/" + noq);
        String firstQuestion = scanner.nextLine();
        questions[i - 1] = firstQuestion;
    }
}

public static void Answer() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= noq; i++) {
        System.out.println(questions[i - 1]);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a answer " + i + "/" + noq);
        String answerAnswer = scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

You should also get away from using static everywhere.  I had to do it to simplify the example. Check out the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for more information on programming in Java focusing on arrays and the uses of the `static` keyword.

Comment: Thank you! this helped me very much, but do u know how to grab that specific input? would I need to call it in threw an array? also uptop would i need to create  a new arary for answers? because downbelow in the array of answers, its using the questions string up top.(idk if that made any sense but i hope u get the point. also thanks for the help its greatly apreciated)

Comment: Yes.  Remember that arrays are 0 based.  So if you want the first item use `questions[0]`, the second would be `questions[1]` and so on.  That is why I subtracted 1 from  your loop variable to index the array.  If you use questions[noq] that will throw an exception because noq = 10, the length of the array. But the last element is questions[9].

Comment: @mangoscoconuts  Did my previous comment address your question?

Comment: Yea, thanks! This helped me learn more, I can get your point, thanks!